# Varying heights of instances based on location

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to vary the z translation of instances on points based on their distance from the origin. Is there a way to do this?
I imagine I must

1. get distance vector values for each instance. Then
2. create an equation which calculates the translation..

Comment: from their origin of what object? maybe a sketch/image would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Is it this, what you are looking for?

[image: result 3d]

[image: node setup]

Comment: Hi, nice answer. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. Could you [edit] your answer and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps explain the solution and add a brief description of the logic used, so it can be index and search by future visitors

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, currently the question is not completely clear. As soon as I know, that this approach goes into the right direction, I will explain it in more detail.

Comment: Can't you just use *Vector Math Distance* (Position / (0, 0, 0)) instead of the *Subtract* and *Length* nodes?

Comment: @Blunder, yes you are right. Thanks! I updated the node setup accordingly.